# Focusrite Saffire Pro 40 query

Tags: audio-interfaces, motu

Hey guys,
So I was planning to buy an interface for myself & I had boiled down to the MOTU 4pre. But the dealer from whom I was planning to buy told me that I could get a Focusrite Saffire Pro 40 8in/8out interface for less price compared to the 4pre.
The thing I want to know is would you ever need so many channels in an interface when you are dealing with film sound? My work mostly consists of sound editing and occasional ADR.
I was looking for something portable but the price factor put me on hold. I'd go for the Pro 40 only if those many channels are useful. What do you think?
Thank You.

Comment: Only you can decide whether that many channels are useful. You can always change later, if your needs change. But I'd say the Focusrite, because it has more for the price.

Answer (score 1):

4pre has 4 outputs. If you ever have to do a 5.1 tracklay, you will need the outputs (especially with 5.1 + 2.0). So you may not need the 8 inputs, but the 8 outs of the Pro 40 make it more appealing for post. The sales guy may be thinking: if you use this for music, certainly you'd appreciate the extra inputs on a drum kit, otherwise - the outputs. That said, I'd still prefer the MOTU, maybe just another model. Some companies have better reputation than others...

Answer (score 0):

I've used to Pro 40 a bit, and it has great features for the price. The MixControl software can be a pretty powerful tool and you will likely find a use for all those outputs (and inputs). The preamps are pretty decent. The only issue I've had with it is a communication glitch between it and Pro Tools. There doesn't seem to be any way to fix it other than restarting the Pro 40. Annoying! But, for what you pay, this is probably tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to say go with the Pro 40 because you can do more with it. You may not have a need for all 8 mic pre's, but in the future that could come in handy very easily.

The Motu isn't going to walk circles around the focusrite.